# How to render string of text in js.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Why does this renders correctly (from an `example.js.erb` file):

```
alert(<%= 123 %>)
```

but not any of these:

```
alert(<%= "hello" %>)
alert(<%= p "hello" %>)
alert(<%= j "hello" %>)
```

?

When I look into the console, the latter are returning strings of text to jquery without quotes, which I believe to be the root of the problem.

But how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The first one will become `alert(123)`, which unsurprisingly displays `123`.
The rest will render `alert(hello)`, which will print the contents of the variable `hello`, presumably empty. What you want is one of these:

```
alert("<%= "hello" %>")
alert(<%= hello.inspect %>)
alert(<%= JSON.dump("hello") %>)
```

(the third one requires some requiring)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, This one is more safe:

```
alert(<% hello&.inspect&.html_safe %>)
```